# increasing the page size PrintVisual in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

I try to print with PrintDialog.PrintVisual, but when the size of the page exceeds one sheet to print lock, anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 4):

1 . Normal Printing:

Printing in WPF is easy as compare to traditional window printing. You need to show the PrintDialog and call the PrintVisual mehod of the PrintDialog. This example has been shown in the btnPrint_OnClick event handler.

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)

{

      printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "First WPF Print");

}
```

2. Print to Fit Window:

Now if you want to fit your visual to fit into the print page then you have to do little more coding.

```
•Add Reference the ReachFramework.dll.
•Add reference of the System.Printing.dll.
•Get the capabilities of the selected printer.
•Calculate the scaling of the printer with w.r.t. to visual to be printed.
•Transform the visual to be printed to the calculated scale.
•Get the printable area of the paper size.
•Update the layout of the visual to the printable area.
•Print the visual.
```

Code: This code in the sample is called in the btnPrintFit_OnClick handler.

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)

   {

      //get selected printer capabilities

      System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);



     //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual

     double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / this.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /

                    this.ActualHeight);



     //Transform the Visual to scale

     this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale); 



     //get the size of the printer page

     Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);



     //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.

     this.Measure(sz); 

     this.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));



      //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.

      printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "First Fit to Page WPF Print");
```